# Uniform convergence of $f_n = x^n - x^{2n}$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I want to find out if the sequence $f_n = x^n - x^{2n}$ converges uniformly for $x \in [0,1]$.

Actually I know that it converges poinwise but It doesn't converge uniformly and I just don't see why.

If I calculate the limit $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} (x^n - x^{2n})$ for $x=0$ and $x=1$ it is zero (note sure about for $x \in (0,1)$)

And if the sequence converges uniformly, we have:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)| = 0$ $\;$ $\;$ $\;$$\;$ (*)

I think the problem would be in evaluating the limit of $f_n(x)$ for $x \in (0,1)$ becauce in $x=1$ and $x=0$ it converges and that would be the pointwise convergence. But I want to know how (*) is going to look like.

Comment: What is the maximum of $f_n$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: You should first compute the pointwise limit $f$. Then you can plug that into (*), and then Lord Shark the Unknown's hint will help you finish the problem.

Comment: I think I see it right now. Thank you.

Comment: (*) is going to be equal 1/2, not zero, if I didn't make a mistake in my calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
f_n(x)=x^n(1-x^n)
$$
So this function converges point-wise to $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ given.  Then we must show that there is $N$ such that
$$
|f_n(x) - f(x)|=|f_n(x)| \le \epsilon
$$ 
for all $n \ge N$ and all $x\in[0,1]$.  Write $z=x^n$.  Then 
$$
f_n(z) = z(1-z) 
$$
which attains its maximum at $z=1/2$.  This occurs when $x=(1/2)^{1/n}$  Hence 
$$
f_n(x) \le (1/2)^{1/n}(1-(1/2)^{1/n}) < 1-(1/2)^{1/n}.
$$
The last expression converges to zero.  Hence for sufficiently large $N$,
$$
f_n(x) \le \epsilon
$$
for $n \ge N$ and for all $x \in [0,1]$.